# How do I wait for a message without the code waiting discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am making a discord bot that essentially just ping spams a person of their choosing. The goal is to get that person online but once they get online I want a way for the person getting spammed to stop it as the bot has already succeed getting that person online.

I tried using client.wait_for("message") but as it says it waits for the message and doesn't continue the loop until it gets a message. Is there a way to activity wait for a message but also have the loop still run?

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  ping = 10
  while ping > 0:
    msg = await client.wait_for("message")
    if msg.content == "stop":
      break
    await ctx.send("test")
    ping = ping - 1
```

Comment: That's not a very good feature to have, can be seen as spam and could break some ToS as well as break discord API abuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a timeout to the `wait_for`

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    ping = 10
    while ping > 0:
        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for("message", timeout=2.0)  # seconds
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:  # import asyncio if you haven't yet
            # do something if we haven't received a message
        else:
            # received a message within n seconds
            if msg.content == "stop":
                break
            await ctx.send("test")
            ping = ping - 1
```

Keep in mind that the timeout should be more than 1 second
as the ratelimit for sending a message is 5 requests per 5 seconds per channel.